# Can you find the pattern behind the proposed letter grouping?

Tags: word, pattern, word-property, letters

Can you complete these groups or identify the pattern behind?

*Example 1:*

```
Group A : {A,C,E,G,I,....}
Group B : {B,....}
```

*Example 2:*

```
Group A : {C,F,I,L,...}
Group B : {E,J,O...}
Group C : {A,B,D,G,H....}
```

*Example 3:*

```
Group A : {A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H}
Group B : {H,I,J,K,L,M,N}
Group C : {N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U}
Group D : {U,V,W,X,Y,Z,A}
```

**Answers:**

*Example #1:*

> Sorting the letters in a 2x13 grid, each row is the same as each group

*Example #2:*

> Counting from A=1, B=2, etc, Group A includes the multiples of 3, Group B includes the multiples of 5 and Group C the remaining letters

*Example #3:*

> Put the letters in the perimeter of a 7x8 square, beginning in the top-left corner and going clockwise. Each side of the square is represented by each group

"That was easy!" you could be thinking...
But, that was the warm-up stage!

---

For the real question, I have found another way to sort the letters and create some groups. Could you find the groups and also identify the pattern I followed to create them?

**Description of the groups:**

- There are 3 main groups, let's call them $A, B$ and $C$. They don't share elements between them, this is: $A \bigcap B = A \bigcap C = B \bigcap C = 0 $
- The relation between the 3 main groups and the pattern, is that there are 6 additional subgroups $SG_1$ to $SG_6$ can be formed with elements from $A,B$ and $C$. These new subgroups represent more precisely the underlying pattern

**Tips:**

- Many words use letters from all 3 main groups, but I will give you some that only use letters from 2 of them:

  - **Words with letters from just 2 groups:** manager, watch, needle, pattern, found, belly, when, main.
  - **Words with letters from all 3 groups:** transformed, dreams, trouble, morning, element, puzzle, riddle.
- The secondary groups can be made in this way: Take 4 letters of one of the main groups, take additional 4 from the next main group and finally take one more from the third main group, thus, each subgroup contains 9 letters and some subgroups share elements.

Based on this information, Can you...

**Identify the 3 main groups?**:
A, B and C.

**Identify the 6 secondary groups?**:
SG1 to SG6.

**Identify what the main and secondary groups represent in the pattern?**

**Tell what is the pattern based on?**

The answer is compound of four letters:

____,____,____,____

---

**EDIT**:
As stated in the comments, it could not be possible to solve the whole question without some additional information. So using hints 1 and 2A will help in solving the first part (main groups)

---

*Any feedback on this post is appreciated (Difficulty, explanation, wording, suggestion...) as well as partial answers, solving procedure, etc*

*Hints policy: A hint will be given every 50 views for the first three hints. After that, 1 hint every 100 views or 15 votes.*

---

**Hint #1 (50 views): (More examples words)**

> More examples that might help you:
>
>   - **Words with letters from just 2 groups:** that,root,week,tree,seeded,bath,day,new,key,yaw
>
>   - **Words with letters from all 3 groups:** than,more,question,back,weak,referrer

**Hint #2 (100 views): (More example words (A) and more details about groups and subgroups (B))**

- Part A:

> - **First of all, additional words for making the grouping easier:**
>
>     - **Words with letters from just 2 groups:** quiz, jacuzzi, two, four, six, june.
>
>     - **Words with letters from all 3 groups** (but this are evenly distributed on the groups, this is, the same number of letter from each group): dreams, answer, december, language, oxygen, neutron, witness,frozen
>
>     - The size of the main groups are 6, 8 and 12.

- Part B:

> -  **Now, more details about the subgroups:**
>
>     - As said before, each subgroup contains 9 elements. And for each subgroup exists a set of 3 subgroups $SG_A$,$SG_B$ and $SG_C$ that their intersection contains one element:
>
>   $$ SG_A \bigcap SG_B \bigcap SG_C = 1 $$
>
>     - Additionally, each subgroup shares more than one element with the other subgroups except one, which has no common elements:
>  
>   $$ SG_A \bigcup SG_X > 1 \text{ }\forall\text{ } X \text{  in \{B,C,D,E\}} $$
>   $$ SG_A \bigcup SG_F = 0 $$
>
>   - And here are the subgroups partially filled:
>   $$ SG_1:\{A,I,D,...\} $$
>   $$ SG_2:\{D,U,M,...\} $$
>   $$ SG_3:\{C,R,L,...\} $$
>   $$ SG_4:\{R,Z,U,...\} $$
>   $$ SG_5:\{F,W,N,...\} $$
>   $$ SG_6:\{I,X,Q,...\} $$

**Hint #3 (150 views): (Additional subgroups details (A) and relation between groups and subgroups (B))**

- Part A:

> Think about how could you sort the 26 letters in a geometric shape using a single wildcard `*`, and then, from that shape generate 6 groups of 9 letters each.
>  For example, if you use a 3 by 9 grid and put a `*` in the middle, you form a rectangle.
>
>
>  `ABCDEFGHI`
>
>  `JKLM*NOPQ`
>
>  `RSTUVWXYZ`

- Part B:

> -  Each letter in the main group $A$ is only present in one subgroup
>
>   -  Each letter in the main group $B$ is only present in three subgroups
>
>   -  Each letter in the main group $C$ is only present in two subgroup

Comment: So I've managed to classify more than half the letters (fourteen) into three groups, but I think there's not yet enough information given to do the rest.

Comment: @Randal'Thor did you use the hint #1?... There are some pieces of information I left out of the question for next hints in case someone could infer the idea without them.

Comment: Yep. Without hint #1 I would've made way less progress.

Answer (score 2):

The three groups are:

1. > E, K, M, N, P, V
2. > A, C, G, I, R, T, X, Z
3. > B, D, F, H, J, L, O, Q, S, U, W, Y

Or in numbers:

1. > 5, 11, 13, 14, 16, 22
2. > 1, 3, 7, 9, 18, 20, 23, 26
3. > 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25

It's notable that all three groups are

> symmetric: every letter is in the same group as its Atbashed inverse.

So far this has been solved by pure logic, using the information given (including in hints #1 and #2) about 2-group words, 3-group words, and symmetric-3-group words. The next step should be a flash of inspiration to understand what these groups and subgroups are.

Comment: That's awesome progress! However, the pattern you noticed (third hidden block) could be seen as a coincidence or a consequence of the original sorting of the letters into the 6 subgroups. Nice work!

Answer (score 2):

Based on Rand al'Thor's sorting of the letters I think I've found the pattern

> Arrange the letters into a $3 \times 3 \times 3$ cube with a * in the middle as follows.
>
> ```
>  Layer 1         Layer 2         Layer 3
>
>  A B C           J K L           R S T
>  D E F           M * N           U V W
>  G H I           O P Q           X Y Z
> ```
>
> Then, the three main groups are the
>  **Corner pieces**
>  {A, C, G, I, R, T, X, Z}
>
>  **Edge pieces**
>  {B, D, F, H, J, L, O, Q, S, U, W, Y}
>
>  **The central pieces on each face**
>  {E, K, M, N, P, V}
>
>  And the **six** subgroups are the letters on each of the **six** faces.
>
>  **Subgroup 1**
>  {A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I}
>  **Subgroup 2**
>  {A, D, G, J, M, O, R, U, X}
>  **Subgroup 3**
>  {A, B, C, J, K, L, R, S, T}
>  **Subgroup 4**
>  {R, S, T, U, V, W, X, Y, Z}
>  **Subgroup 5**
>  {C, F, I, L, N, Q, T, W, Z}
>  **Subgroup 6**
>  {G, H, I, O, P, Q, X, Y, Z}

Comment: rot13(jryy qbar! Qvq lbh hfr gur 3eq uvag?)

Comment: @gustavovelascoh Yes, I did. I hadn't realised how recently you put that up.